# NullPointerException in setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml

This is really frustrating me and none of the other questions solved my problem.

I'm using a test app from a book, and copied all the code verbatim.  Everything was running fine earlier, but when I tried to make my own style, it started crashing.  So I undid everything and deleted the XML file for the style, and it's still crashing.

What happens is I click on the app, the background for the app appears, but none of the buttons I added come up; instead, it says "Unfortunately, (appname) has stopped."

The console isn't giving me any problems, but here's what LogCat says:

```
12-29 20:45:29.346: D/AndroidRuntime(2606): Shutting down VM
12-29 20:45:29.346: W/dalvikvm(2606): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.recipesapp/com.recipesapp.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at com.recipesapp.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:16)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-29 20:45:29.394: E/AndroidRuntime(2606):     ... 11 more
12-29 20:45:35.215: I/Process(2606): Sending signal. PID: 2606 SIG: 9
```

The only one I recognized was the`java.lang.NullPointerException at com.recipesapp.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:16)` so I zeroed in on that.  And it turns out that when I comment out line 16 there, the app runs fine; however, I can't figure out why it's causing a problem.

Here is the error-generating code, with line 16 noted.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.main_about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);    //LINE 16
    }

    public void onClick(View thisView) {
        switch (thisView.getId()) {
            case R.id.main_about_button:
                Intent showAbout = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(showAbout);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.recipesapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".About"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the code in layout/main.xml for the button in question:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/exit_button"
        android:text="@string/main_about_button" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're mixing up the name of the Button.

Java:

```
View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.main_about_button);
```

XML:

```
android:id="@+id/about_button"
```

Either change the second to `@+id/main_about_button` or the first to `R.id.about_button` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have solved it.
Curiously enough, when I ran that, I got the console message

`[2011-12-29 20:00:12 - BasicRecipes] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.recipesapp/.MainMenu }
[2011-12-29 20:00:17 - BasicRecipes] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2011-12-29 20:00:17 - BasicRecipes] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-12-29 20:00:17 - BasicRecipes] Launch canceled!`

But then it ran anyway.  Any idea on why that would be?

Comment: Did you check if LogCat provided any extra information? And did it only show once or each time you launch it? I haven't come across that specific error yet and can't find any obvious errors in the manifest. Try a project clean and uninstall the app before running it again.

Comment: It actually ran anyway, and then it hasn't complained since.  I'm going to assume it was something Android had stored from one of the previous runs that clashed with one of the changes I made, because immediately afterwards, I ran it again while changing absolutely nothing in the code and the error didn't pop up again.